# Web API Passing int[] to Get Not Via Querystring

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am in the process of writing a C# HttpClient to invoke a Web Api GET method, which accepts an int[]. In reality this array could be thousands of bytes so I do not want to pass it via the querystring, In this situation, should I use SendAsync? Post? What are my options?

thanks in advance

M

Comment: Post is correct... No need of addtional options

Comment: `Post` is the way to go.